# Youtube V3 - LiveChatMessages.list only returns a max of 75 requests

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

When I try and send the following request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?liveChatId={..}&part=snippet&maxResults=250key={...}
```

I only get a max of 75 results returned even though there are more than 75 comments in my livestream. These 75 comments returned are also the 75 newest comments. Setting the `nextPageToken` with the value in the response above returns an empty set of comments. It's almost like I need a way to view previous pages. Setting `maxResults`, as I have in the url above does nothing as well. When I add a new comment to the livestream, the first entry of the 75 disappears and the new comment shows up at the bottom of the list.

I am perplexed over why I cannot receive more than 75 comments and why the number 75 as this is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.  Do you guys have any idea whats going on here? I can provide more information as needed.

Comment: Are you receiving a page token? Does supplying it give you the next 75?

Comment: I do receive a page token but supplying it doesn't give me the remaining comments that were missing from the original request.  I just get an empty set in the items field of the response

Comment: To clarify what i am doing, here are the steps:

1) Start a livestream and use liveBroadcasts#list to fetch the livechatid

2) Use the livechatid in LiveChatMessages#list to fetch the comments from the livestream

3) The first time I do this, I get no comments. This makes sense since my livestream has no comments

4) I go back to my livestream on the youtube page and I type the numbers 1-76 into the comment section. 1 is the oldest comment and 76 is the newest comment

5) At this point, I have 76 comments in my chat.

Comment: 6) I go back here (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list#try-it) and i now try and retrive these comments
7) However, only the comments with payloads 2-76 appear and I cant seem to get the comment with a text of '1' to show up.

The page token returned in the response only gets me comments made after the comment with the 76 in it. The comment with the '1' is just lost

Comment: Does this problem occur if the comments are below 75- like 5 or 10? It's hard to know what the real error is since we cannot see your livechat comments and the response body from your URI request.

Comment: @KPERI did you find a solution? i'm also only getting 75 messages and using the nextpage i get none. even though the last one in the 75 count is my last test message

Comment: @jasan Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

Having testing the liveChatMessages google youtube-api with the most active rooms I could find and reviewing the documentation I have concluded that when you query the the liveChatMessages api you get the 75 most recent messages ordered from oldest to newest, and the nextTokenId given if added to the next query will return any more recent messages which have been gathered by Google's servers since your first query. I am not sure how to get older messages, it does not seem possible.